# CSS setting two elements inline within responsive div

Tags: html, css

Long time user of Stack Overflow, first time question! So here goes.

I have a very basic html mark up with a div, containing an input box and a button, styled inline.

The button positioned on the right is a set width of 90px.
The input box needs to fill up the rest of the space between the left of the parent div and the button.

So I basically need both the input and the button to fill the parent div, although one is a fixed width and one will potentially change based on device.

The problem is, as the parent div is responsive and ever changing, I can't set a certain width on the input box to make it fill all available space as far as the button.

To make it worse, I can't used a simple javascript solution or a nice css calc() solution applied to the input box (for example calc(100% - buttonWidth)).

Maybe I've been programming for too many hours now and I can't see the simple solution in front of me. Any Ideas?

Many thanks in advance.

Code Sample:

/*HTML*/

```
<div id="parent">
    <input type="text" name="rq" id="rq" value="" x-webkit-speech/>
    <button id="search_btn" class="btn-blue">
    </button>
</div>
```

/*CSS*/

```
#parent{
    min-height: 123px;
    border: solid 3px #1B8BDE;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #DCECf7;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 234px;
}
#rq{
    width: 93%;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 6px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}
#search_btn{
    width: 90px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: -3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    border-color: rgb(22, 96, 168);
    background-color: rgb(0, 140, 226);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid rgb(22, 96, 168);
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    display: inline;
}
```

As I said, the issue is a way to set the width of the input to take up all the parent divs width minus the button without using javascript or css's calc; this is because the parent div will be always changing width.

Comment: Can you post your code? - perhaps a jsfiddle too?

Comment: Well my current code is quite different as for a work around I have the the input box taking up 95% of the parent div with the button floating to the right of it covering it partially.

I'll update my opening comment with the basic html/css mark up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the table display properties of css:

```
<div>
<div class="col"><input type="text"></div>
<div class="col"><button>test</button></div>  
</div>
```

css

```
div{
width:100%;
display: table;
}
button{
width:90px;
}

.col {
display: table-cell;
}

.col input{
width: 100%;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H8q6b/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `width:auto` on the input element?

Comment: Thank you Kindly Mr.Stetler. It never occurred to me to use table styles.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment with too low rep. but here's a really quick jsfiddle for anyone that wants to play around with ideas:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div style="height:200px; width: 100%; background-color:#000">hi

<span style="width:90px; background-color:#fff">hello</span>
<input style="background-color:#f00; position:relative; width: auto; display:inline" />

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ruxp3/

(I'll remove this when the answer is accepted, apologies for not segregating css - very fast fiddle creation)